# Appending keyed row values in column chunks in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Problem: I have multiple rows with unique organizations and if a unique row's column reaches the second name/last/email I want those values (in green) to be appended below the first (in blue) as seen in "what I want". Some rows may only have data up to email_1 and others may have both (up to email_2). I've tried looking for solutions but I can't find anything near what I need.

I can solve this with python but I'm trying to use ***excel*** formulas only. Need a little help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There is no formula that can insert a row in Excel. Therefore you will need code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column maximum limit is upto email_2 means columns reach upto email_2 with unique row  then i can help  you in this regards using formula.use following steps.

1. paste first_2, lastname_2 etc column in above first_name, last_name etc.

2.in unique rows first column "Org". use if function to check first_2 is avaliable or not.
and if not there then leave it blank and move next row
=IF(IF(LEN(F5)>0,B5,B6)=B6,"",B5)
[image: step 2 Image]

3.for getting data of first_2, last_2 use vlookup with match formula are as follow
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B9,$B$4:$H$8,MATCH(C$3,$B$4:$H$4,0),0),"") and after drag and drop all formula

[image: Step 3 image]